# Dynamic Routing by Hostname only - Kubernetes Ingress Rules

Tags: kubernetes, dynamic, routes, dns, kubernetes-ingress

I have a K8s cluster with multiple different services deployed and would like to use a single `Ingress` to route each incoming request to the appropriate service via a unique hostname `DNS`.

Currently, I've only been able to resolve a request when using the root path i.e. `service-123.app.com`.

As soon as I try to make a request with a path it doesn't resolve. The paths are valid paths to each service. For example, `service-123.app.com/page/12345` would be expected by the application.

I might not fully understand how K8s Ingress rules are expected to work, but I hoped that it would match based on hostname only and simply forward on the path to the appropriate service.

Am I missing something very simple here? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Here are my config files.

**Ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ......
  name: app-name
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: service-123.app.com
    http:
      - path: "/*"
        backend:
          serviceName: service-123
          servicePort: 80
  - host: service-456.app.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/*"
        backend:
          serviceName: service-456
          servicePort: 80
```

**service.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations: {}
  labels:
    app: service-123
  name: service-123
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: port8080
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: service-123
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: Hi user2252867. What Kubernetes version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which K8s and ingress controller you are using, but in the later K8s you can specify the [`pathType`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types) which takes care of path wildcards more nicely.

You would have something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ......
  name: app-name
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: service-123.app.com
    http:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: service-123
          servicePort: 80
  - host: service-456.app.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: service-456
          servicePort: 80
```

If you are using an [nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) a good way to see the right nginx configuration is by looking at the actual `nginx.conf` generated by the ingress controller.

```
$ kubectl cp <nginx-ingress-controller-pod>:nginx.conf nginx.conf
$ cat nginx.conf
```